# Encountering some problems with gnome-terminal startup and maximize button!

Tags: gnome-terminal, maximized

[image: Some problems with gnome-terminal and maximize button]

Hi, have been a linux user for more than an year now. I have used mint for most of the time and switched to ubunutu a month back. I have some issue with the maximize button, when I press maximize the window sort of shrinks to the top left of the screen, this happens 90% percent of the time I press maximize, as you can see, one can only again resize it with a cursor or use keyboard shortcut to maximize again.

Second problem is with gnome-terminal, I did not have any problems with it until today, on start up the cursor turns into a crosshair like shape and then it takes loads of time to load the prompt and get started, click and drag draws some rectangle on the terminal as you can see. I figured the problem maybe with some config I changed and hence I purged gnome-terminal and also ran the command `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/` and installed it again. Still the same issue persists. I have no idea what went wrong.

PS: Yes that's ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the machine?

Comment: Yes I did @wjandrea. The maximize issue persisted since the time of installation and terminal, yeah only today and I restarted multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal thing was because I had accidently pasted `import sys` in .bashrc while editing prompt. It was figured glad that I was able to figure that out.

And that maximize still exists, it existed right from the start. I still don't know why that is.